# trim and ucase functions for insert parameter query

Tags: ms-access

Please give me the SQL to convert the text in this parameter append query to uppercase and remove empty spaces from the prefix and sufffix.  Thank you very much in advance, Nathaniel

```
INSERT INTO tbl_New_part_ID_input ( new_part_ID )
```

SELECT [please enter   part_ID in UPPERCASE] AS Expr1;

Comment: If you are working in MS Access, you should be using a form, not a parameter query, and then you would not have these problems. If you are not, you should say what language you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use any SQL or VBA functions inside query. For example

```
PARAMETER new_part_ID  as String;
INSERT INTO tbl_New_part_ID_input ( Trim(UCase([new_part_ID])) )
```